# Java 8 Query - Grouping calculation based on Key with Multiple Lists of Objects

Tags: java, java-8

I needed some help with a Java 8 solution to calculate totals.
Suppose that I have 3 item objects and each of these objects contain a list of (2 or 3) tax objects. Please find below a detailed imaging of this object -

Item 1
(List)
Tax 1 - Id-1 | Name-A | Desc | Amount-Rs.5 | More objects
Tax 2 - Id-2 | Name-B | Desc | Amount-Rs.10 | More objects
Tax 3 - Id-3 | Name-C | Desc | Amount-Rs.8 | More objects

Item 2
(List)
Tax 1 - Id-1 | Name-A | Desc | Amount-Rs.9 | More objects
Tax 3 - Id-3 | Name-C | Desc | Amount-Rs.10 | More objects

Now,
I have created a new Object (Aggregate) that needs to be the total based on Id
For ex: The above information should be have 3 aggregate objects with amounts summed 
Tax-1 | Name-A | Desc | Amount-Rs.14
Tax-2 | Name-B | Desc | Amount-Rs.10
Tax-2 | Name-B | Desc | Amount-Rs.18

I was able to achieve this by looping through each object and adding it to a map <String Id,Object Aggregate>. If the keys existed, I would pull out the amount value from the Object Aggregate and add the amount to the existing amount. If not, I would create a new Aggregate object and add it to the map but I was hoping if there was a more optimised way to do this in Java 8

Global variable - `Map<String, Aggregate> taxAggreg`

```
for (Item item: Items) {
    List < Tax > taxes = item.getTaxes;
    for (Tax tax: taxes) {
        createTax(Tax tax);
    }
}

private void createTax(Tax tax) {
    if (!taxAggreg.isEmpty() && taxAggreg.containsKey(tax.getTaxId())) {
        Aggregate aggreg = taxAggreg.get(tax.getTaxId());
        aggreg.setTaxAmount(aggreg.getTaxAmount().add(tax.getTaxAmount()));
        taxAggreg.put(tax.getTaxId(), aggreg);
    } else {
        taxAggreg.put(tax.getTaxId(), new Aggregate(tax.getTaxId(), tax.getName(),
            tax.getTaxAmount()));
    }
}
```

Comment: Added the logic in the question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First, flat the list of tag for item, then transform the Tax object into Aggregate object. Then map by tax id using `Collectors.toMap` then merge tax objects with same id.

```
Map<Integer, Aggregate> resMap = items.stream()
                .flatMap(item -> item.getTaxes().stream())
                .map(tax -> new Aggregate(tax.getTaxId(), tax.getName(), tax.getTaxAmount()))
                .collect(Collectors.toMap(Tax::getTaxId, e -> e,    
                                  (a, b) -> new Aggregate(a.getTaxId(), a.getName(), 
                                                   a.getTaxAmount().add(b.getTaxAmount()))));
```

Here using `Collectors.toMap` map by `Tax::getTaxId` which is the first parameter of toMap. The next one is the key of the map `e -> e` for the whole `Aggregate` obj as key. And finally, the last parameter in the merge function will be used for merging two `Aggregate` objects into one `Aggregate` object so that all values of the same key merged into one `Aggregate` object

```
Collectors.toMap(Tax::getTaxId, e -> e,    
                    (a, b) -> new Aggregate(a.getTaxId(), a.getName(),
                                            a.getTaxAmount().add(b.getTaxAmount())))
```

Comment: Did you try this ?

Comment: I just came online. I'm going to try the solutions provided. Thank you for the input. I'll get back to you in sometime.

Comment: Can you please explain what you did in the toMap?

Comment: I ask this question because your creating a new aggregate object where in we should only be modifying the existing value in the aggregate object.

Comment: @JustinPeter Explanation added

Comment: Yes first create all tax object into Aggregate object then process the aggregate object using toMap

Answer (score 0):

Maybe something like this could work:

```
    List<Aggregate> list1 = new ArrayList<Aggregate>();      
    List<Aggregate> list2 = new ArrayList<Aggregate>();    

    // Add your data to lists...

    // Now create maps with the identity for each object in lists
    Map<String, Aggregate> aggregateMap1 = list1.stream().collect(Collectors.toMap(Aggregate::getId, Function.identity()));
    Map<String, Aggregate> aggregateMap2 = list2.stream().collect(Collectors.toMap(Aggregate::geId, Function.identity()));

    // Now merge lists and add the amounts together
    List<Aggregate> result = aggregateMap1.keySet().forEach(key -> aggregateMap1.merge(key,
            aggregateMap2.get(key),
            (aggr1, aggr2) -> {
                aggr1.setAmount(aggr1.getAmount() + aggr2.getAmount());
                return aggr1;
            })).values().stream().collect(Collectors.toList());;
```

Not tested. Also could be fine tuned.

Comment: I just came online. I'm going to try the solutions provided. Thank you for the input. I'll get back to you in sometime.

Comment: Question to you. Are we creating a list out of each items aggregate? because if thats the case. The list of items can be dynamic could result in unnecessary usage of memory. And your summing up each aggregate into the first map we have if im not wrong?

Comment: True. If you want to keep your aggregates as they are you should instead create a new object and return it as in aggr = new Aggregate(); aggr.setAmount(aggr1.getAmount() + aggr2.getAmount()); return aggr;